# VideoView not playing video from storage

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I'm trying to play video file from storage by following codes:

```
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("video/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_OPEN_AUDIO_MP3);
                }
            });



    button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
                    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getContext());
                    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                    videoView.requestFocus();
                    videoView.start();

                    return false;
                }
            });


    @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                if (requestCode==RQS_OPEN_VIDEO_MP4){
                    uri = data.getData();
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm doing the longclick just for test and I get the effect type 0 while long press, what I actually want is to play video when I choose the file.
what am I missing?(nothing looks odd)

Comment: ```videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/filepath.mp4") ``` this might help

Comment: @dastan doesn't work

Comment: what is not working, you can get path or video not playing, and I think sotrage read permission you have already added in manifest

Comment: @dastan when I put an image and i set the view to image view when I choose a picture from storage it is showing in the image view but when i set the view to videoview and I choose the video file nothing happens